# How can set element alignment which is inside parent with the child style setting in element style attributes?

Tags: html, css

```
.popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
  }

  .popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
  }
```

I have above codes in my css file that added in html head `<link href="/static/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">`

In my html there where many uses of `.popup`and `.popuptext` and I wont change above styles.

In the html code is here↓

```
<div class="popup" style="display: inline"><div class="popuptext" id="tableHeader">
    <label>data type</label>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="not_null"> NOT NULL
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="unique"> UNIQUE
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="delete">Delete</button>
</div></div>
```

All elements above are aligned as center.

[image]

But I need centralize the `Delete` button and the `label` and other `input` elements be left aligned.

As I consist change style from html code and stylesheet has other uses, I have tried below↓

```
<div class="popup" style="display: inline"><div class="popuptext" id="tableHeader">
    <label>data type</label>
    <br>
    <span style="text-align: left;"><input type="checkbox" name="not_null"> NOT NULL</span>
    <br>
    <span style="text-align: left;"><input type="checkbox" name="unique"> UNIQUE</span>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="delete">Delete</button>
</div></div>
```

But input elements remain centralist and not left aligned!

**I need `input` get left aligned only with change style settings in html element attributes.**

Comment: instead of using `br`s why not just wrap them in divs and add text align center to the divs you want centred.  Also your html seems to be mismatched - you have an extra closing span and a missing closing div

Comment: @Pete, Thank you. I have edited my code. I well wrap them in divs. you right. there are text align center now. I need two type item been left aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving the html as it is, you could style the `.popuptext` children as `display:block` so that they will take the whole width. Then you can style indipendently its parts:

1. The `<label>` element - its content gets centered with `text-align: center`
2. The `<input>` elements - they get aligned to left with `text-align: left;` but just because we are actually styling their parents
   `<span>`
3. The `<button>` element - this required `margin: 0 auto` meaning that the left
   and right margins will be set to the maximum available space in the
   row

Everything else in the styles here in the demo is for decoration purpose.

```css
.popup{
  border: solid;
  width: 10em;
  background: lightgray;
}

.popuptext > *{
  display: block;
}

.popuptext > span{
  text-align: left;
}

.popuptext > label{
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
.popuptext > button{
  margin: .5em auto;
  border: none;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: .8em .6em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">
  <div class="popuptext" id="tableHeader">
    <label>data type</label>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="not_null"> NOT NULL</span>
    <span><input type="checkbox" name="unique"> UNIQUE</span>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="delete">Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can restructure your HTML and CSS as such:

```css
        .popup .popuptext {
            width: 160px;
            background-color: #555;
            color: #fff;
            border-radius: 6px;
            padding: 8px 0;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .popuptext .checkbox-holder {
            width: fit-content;
            margin: auto;
        }
```

```html
<div class="popup" style="display: inline">
        <div class="popuptext" id="tableHeader">
            <div style="text-align: center;"><label>data type</label></div>

            <div class="checkbox-holder">
                <div><input type="checkbox" name="not_null" id="not_null"> <label for="not_null">NOT NULL</label></div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" name="unique" id="unique"> <label for="unique">UNIQUE</label></div>
            </div>


            <div style="text-align:center"><button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="delete">Delete</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```